Using the value of a global KOMA option
How can I use the value of DIV in my own calculations, is there a \the\DIV or something similar?
\documentclass[ngerman,parskip=full,twoside, DIV=11,headinclude,footinclude ]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

Hello

\end{document}


Simplest method: Parse the class options yourself to get it.

I skimmed through the sources of typearea.sty, and without any warranty I'd think that you're after the count register \ta@div. Note however that this is undocumented territory so might be subject to changes. Please note that any value of \ta@div below 4 seems to be a magic value.

Indeed this is the key, thanks.

Because you are able to read German: Abfrage der gesetzten Optionen.

There is an experimental feature in KOMA-Script to get the values of KOMA-Script options. AFAIK this is currently documented only in scrkernel-scrbase.dtx and in German on komascript.de.
\documentclass[ngerman,parskip=full,twoside, DIV=11,headinclude,footinclude ]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

The current active setting of \texttt{typarea}'s \KOMAScript{} option
\texttt{DIV} is \KOMAoptionOf[\texttt]{typearea.sty}{DIV}.

\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}
The current active setting of \texttt{typarea}'s \KOMAScript{} option
\texttt{DIV} is \KOMAoptionOf[\texttt]{typearea.sty}{DIV}.

\KOMAoptionOf[\def\DIVvalue]{typearea.sty}{DIV}
\texttt{\meaning\DIVvalue}

\expandafter\the\csname ta@div\endcsname

\end{document}

As you can see, \KOMAoptionOf really returns the value of the option not the divisor used to calculate the page layout. The used divisor is AFAIK only available in the internal TeX counter \ta@div.
